# Error instalación paquetes Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

Al intentar instalar el paquete `axios` en `Vue js` usando `npm install --save axios vue-axios` obtengo el siguiente error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @vue/cli-plugin-router@3.12.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Estoy usando Vue2, con `vue-router` y `vuex`.

Contenido del `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "lint-staged": "^12.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,vue}": [
      "vue-cli-service lint",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

Llevo días intentando resolver este problema pero no lo he conseguido, alguna idea?

Comment: Por favor, publica el contenido de tu `package.json`.

Comment: En `devDependencies` tenés `"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "3.12.1",` (que es lo que te menciona el error). ¿En verdad existe esa versión?

Answer (score 0):

Por alguna razón cli-plugin-router no tiene versión 3.12.1 https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/v3/packages/@vue

En npm tampoco
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-router

Vas a necesitar cambiar estas líneas

```
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.1.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "3.12.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.1",
```

por

```
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.15",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.15",
"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.15",
"@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.5.15",
"@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.15",
```

y volver a intentar con

```
npm install --save axios vue-axios
```

Comment: He cambiado la línea y al intentar compilar me sucede lo siguiente: `ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error Syntax Error: TypeError: eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor


You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.`

Comment: Respuesta editada.

Comment: El error sigue siendo el mismo aún cambiando estas líneas, me da a mi que el archivo `package` no tiene la culpa.

Comment: `"eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0",` y has un `npm install` nuevo